# Compiler error in C, Error : Expected Expression

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have run into a problem I don't really know how to fix. I mostly code in Python, and this is my first program in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ask(void) {
  scanf("Var");
  return 0;
}

int count(ask) {
  scanf("number1");
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("This is my first program!\n");
  printf("I hope this program turns out well.");
  printf("I don't really know what to do, but i think im progressing.\n");
  printf("But yeah, This is my first program.\n");
  printf("Type an Number");
  ask();
  count(ask());
  printf("Thanks!");
  printf(%count%);
  return 0;
}
```

However, I keep getting an error.

```
main.c:22:10: error: expected expression
  printf(%count%);
         ^
main.c:22:17: error: expected expression
  printf(%count%);
                ^
2 errors generated.
compiler exit status 1
```

What I want it to do is, the user types a number, and then it prints out that number. It's not complete though. I want it to write numbers 1 - the users input, and when it gets the number right, it prints "Your number is:" (number)

Comment: If you want to print the value returned by `count`, your syntax is wrong. It's difficult to say an easy fix though because your `count` function isn't using `scanf` properly either, so there's multiple things that need to be fixed. You'd need `printf("%d", count());`, then have `count` return a valid value.

Comment: `scanf("Var");` isn't going to do very much. Also a variable name `%count%` can't begin or end in `%`.

Comment: You really need to read up on how to use `scanf` and `printf` in C. The syntax for those in Python is clearly very different. And why should they be the same - they are very different languages?

Comment: The text says "I don't really know what to do" but guesswork isn't going to help!

Comment: I already knew guesswork wouldn't help, that's why i asked it on stackoverflow, and ended up getting downvoted. Classic Stack Overflow... 

Whenever i ask a question, i prepare to get downvoted, it seems it's how stack overflow works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (as already pointed out) is that you aren't actually getting and storing the value from the scanf() call. Additionally, `printf(%count%)` is not valid C syntax. You need to use `printf("%d", count)`.

Putting all that together:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int ask(void) {
  int input_number;
  scanf("%d", &input_number);
  getchar();  # This is so that the '\n' in is read when you hit Enter
  return input_number;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("This is my first program!\n");
  printf("I hope this program turns out well.");
  printf("I don't really know what to do, but i think im progressing.\n");
  printf("But yeah, This is my first program.\n");
  printf("Type an Number");
  int input_number = ask();
  printf("Thanks!");
  printf("The number you entered is %d\n", input_number);
  return 0;
}
```

Some things to read to avoid making mistakes like these:

`printf` tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

`scanf` tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to know  how to store values but assumed i didn't need to. This worked :)

Comment: If the solution fixed your problem could you please approve the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect format for printing.
you are using this code  `printf(%count%);`   instead you should use this code `printf("%d",count(variablename));`

Here is the code that you can use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int ask(void) {
    //scanf("Var");
    int var; //declaring integer type varible in C
    scanf("%d",&var);  //taking input

    return var; //returning what is being input by user
 }

//int count(ask) //its function you are passing
//so it should have parenthesis
int count( int a ) 
{

      return a;

 }

  int main(void) {
   printf("This is my first program!\n");
   printf("I hope this program turns out well.");
   printf("I don't really know what to do, but i think im progressing.\n");
   printf("But yeah, This is my first program.\n");
   printf("Type an Number: ");

           //ask();   
    count(ask()); // when you will call it will automatically run ask as well 
           // and it will pass int value that user will input 
    printf("Thanks!");
    int var1=ask();   // this varible var1 will store value returned by ask() 
    printf("%d",count(var1) );  //this will print that value

                 //I dont know what you wanted to do here
                 //maybe you wanted to print value returned by count function
                 //so it can be done by this
   return 0;
}
```

printf format:  `printf("%formatspecifier",variable name);`   Format specifiers are `%d` for a integer. `%f` for a floating value. `%c` for a charcater. `s` for a string and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In C, we use `%` to specify output/input type. %d for integer, %f for float, %c for character, %s for string and thats your basic knowledge.

for printf:

`printf("%d", varname);`

for scanf:

`scanf("%d", &varname);`

'&' means location in memory.

Your program got many syntax errors, here is some code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int ask(){
    
    int varin;
    
    scanf("%d", &varin);
    return (varin);
}

int count(int countin){
    return (countin);   //just an example code, or whatever you wanna do here.
}

int main(){
    
    int out;
    
    printf("Whatever\n");
    out = ask();
    count(out);
    printf("%d", out);
    
    return 0;
}
```